# loading image using javascript FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, file, binary, filereader

I want to load some kind of file(in this case an image) using javascript FileReader API. Following is a snippet of my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    result = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

the 'file' variable has File type and work properly. you just focus on above
code.

After running above code, if i look at reader.result.byteLength it has true size, but reader.result hasn't any data. why?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    reader.result = reader.result;
    //this.result = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Comment: yes, that works, but why? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: if the object is not specified it will be stored in global scope.. To test with your old code, just check result (not reader.result).

Comment: Sorry, that's not working, i have a mistake in calling funciton.